# Passing parameters in .jcall

Tags: r, rjava

I have just started working with rJava to utilise a host of Java code in an R based application. I've tried some simple "Hello world" type things so I know the basic setup is working. I have several issues however I am hoping they will be resolved if I can resolve this basic problem using `.jcall`.

```
> cal = new(J("java/util/GregorianCalendar"))
> obj = new(J("au.gov.ips.dataarchive.TIndex"))
> obj$monthlyT(cal)
[1] 77
> .jcall(obj,"I","monthlyT",cal)
    Error in .jcall(obj, "I", "monthlyT", cal) : 
     method monthlyT with signature (Ljava/util/GregorianCalendar;)I not found
```

To my understanding, the 3rd and 4th lines are equivalent and should produce the same result. Clearly I am doing something wrong. The 'monthlyT' method is defined in the java code as:

```
static public Integer monthlyT(Calendar month)
```

I am not a Java expert, so please let me know what other info about the Java objects I might need to provide to answer the question.

Comment: "I" is for an int return type. you are returning java.lang.Integer. .jcall is persnickety about these things.

Comment: Thanks. Could you expand on that? I've now tried .jcall(obj,"Ljava/lang/Integer;","monthlyT",cal) with no success. What is the exact syntax required here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cal` is a `java.util.GregorianCalendar` and not a `java.util.Calendar`. If you want to use the low-level `.jcall` interface (why?) then you need to do the casting yourself. So something like this:

```
.jcall(obj,"I","monthlyT",.jcast(cal, "java/util/Calendar" ))
```